# Zoom patches exchange

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects, effects-pedal

Is it possible to use [Zoom G3](https://www.zoom.co.jp/products/guitar/g3-guitar-effects-amp-simulator-pedal) (or any other from zoom family) patches on [Zoom G3XN](https://www.zoom.co.jp/products/guitar-bass-effects/guitar/g3xn-multi-effects-processor)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You can use G3 and G3X patches almost interchangeably, but the -N kit uses a different processor, and the patches aren't compatible.

There is a [Zoom G3/G3X/G3XN Facebook user group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ZoomG3.G3xuser/) that may be useful to you.

Comment: So from other side I can use patch for G5XN on my G3XN?

Comment: Yes - it looks like you can go between the 3 and 5, but if going the other way you need to ensure your patches are limited.